# Python Def (Define Function) not executed to strip dataframe

Tags: python, function, strip

Below is a dataframe and the goal is to strip the column as well as the dataframe values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A ': ['1   ', '   2  '], '  B': ['4 ', '5 '], 'C': ['8 ','9']})
```

### |A  |  B|C|

### |1  |4 |8 |

### | 2 |5 |9|

```
def strip(data):
    data.columns = data.columns.str.strip()
    data = data.applymap(str.strip)
```

But it's not working (return the spaced dataframe) when execute the function as below, but when remove the def() it can work

```
strip(df)
```

How to use the def() in order to strip the data? Looking forward to your solutions. Thank you so much!

Comment: See [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/986006/5987)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the dataframe, and assign it back. Because the operation you are doing is immutable, a new copy of the dataframe is created within the scope of function `strip`, and the outer object has no effect.

```
def strip(data):
    data.columns = data.columns.str.strip()
    data = data.applymap(str.strip)
    return data

df = strip(df)
```